# First div fixed, second full width. Cant change structure of html

Tags: css

Have problem. I have this code.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

I need to make two colums.
"Sidebar" must have fixed width 200px; 
And "content" all remaining width to fullscreen.

I cant change the structure of html code, just css.

Comment: `width: calc(100% - 200px);`

Comment: I tried to make sidebar "position absolute". And content "position relative" with "margin left". But content became too large and out of bounds of 'main'

Comment: "calc" as I know has not good compatibility with mobile devices as i know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if absolute position is ok, you can use it to say `left:200px; right:0` and get all the space you need

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/h2udmqhn/

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use float: left for `.sidebar` and left margin for `.content`:

```
.sidebar {float: left; width: 200px; background: red;}
.content {background: green; margin: 0 0 0 200px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/orty5qtj/1/

Another option is to use `calc`, which is unsupported in IE8. The solution above works fine in all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
.sidebar {
  float: left;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
 }

.content {
  background : yellow;
  margin-left: 200px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Saiyam/5krmkkkx/3/

Answer (score 1):

There a couple of simple ways to do this without the need for calc, margins or absolute positioning.  Both of the following ways have the added bonus of keeping the columns the same height as each other

**Using display table (compatible to back ie8)**

```css
.main {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.main > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
.content {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidebar">200px</div>
  <div class="content">the rest</div>
</div>
```

**Using flex (for newer browsers only unless used with the browser prefix)**:

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    flex: 0 0 200px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.content {
    background-color:red;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">200px</div>
    <div class="content">the rest</div>
</div>
```